# Remove all occurences of elem from any level of a list in Common-lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, removeall

I want to solve this problem using mapcar/lambdas. I know how to do it regularly. So far I have something like:

```
(defun removal (lista elem &optional final)
    (cond
       ((and (atom lista) (eql lista elem))  nil)
       ((listp lista) (mapcan (lambda (e) ( removal e elem final)) lista))
       (t (nconc final lista))))
```

For some reason, it's not even running so far but this is a draft. Any ideas where to put the mapcar or how to get rid of the optional list final? I need to solve this using either map functions or lambdas and recursion.

Still not working properly even after adding the lambda and mapcan, it won't construct a list at all

Comment: A short introduction to style and formatting:  http://people.ace.ed.ac.uk/staff/medward2/class/moz/cm/doc/contrib/lispstyle.html

Comment: You mention mapcar/lambda, but you might also find [**mapcan** or **mapcon**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is not clear what kind of constrains do you have, here there are two solutions, the first one recursive, without higher order functions, and the second one with a higher order function.

```
(defun remove-from-tree(el tree)
  (cond ((null tree) nil)
        ((consp (car tree))
         (cons (remove-from-tree el (car tree))
               (remove-from-tree el (cdr tree))))
        ((eql (car tree) el) (remove-from-tree el (cdr tree)))
        (t (cons (car tree) (remove-from-tree el (cdr tree))))))
```

In this solutions there are four possible cases in the `cond`:

1. if the tree is empty, then return an empty tree,
2. if the first element of the tree is a cons, that is a tree, apply recursively the function to both the car and the cdr of the original tree, and cons the results to obtain the new tree,
3. (at this point we know that the car of the tree is an atom), if the car is `eql` to the element, then ignore the car and continue to apply recursively the function to the cdr,
4. otherwise, build a new tree with the car (which is an atom that differs from the element) and the result of applying the function to the cdr of the tree.

Here is the second version:

```
(defun remove-from-tree(el tree)
  (mapcan (lambda(subtree)
            (cond ((null subtree) (list nil))
                  ((consp subtree) (list (remove-from-tree el subtree)))
                  ((eql subtree el) nil)
                  (t (list subtree))))
          tree))
```

In this case the functional `mapcan` is used, and since this `nconc` all the results, we must add `list` to several branches of the `cond` of the inner function.

The inner function, which is applied to the “top” elements of the tree, has four cases:

1. if the subtree is null, the value returned is `(list nil)` so that the `mapcan` can concatenate this result to the others,
2. if the subtree is a cons, that is a tree, call recursively the function on it and return a list of the result,
3. (at this point we know that the subtree is an atom), if it is equal to the element to be removed, return `nil` (and this will not appear in the result of the `mapcan`),
4. finally, returns the atom, different from the element, as a list.

Answer (score 3):

Some remarks:

- when you deal with multiple levels of lists, you are typically working with a tree, aren't you? I would replace `removal` and `lista` by `tree-remove` and `tree`.
- what if `lista` is an atom, but not a number? you'd better check if `lista` is a number before using `=`, or maybe accept a `:test` argument.
- You are saying that *for some reason, it's not even running*. Don't you have an error message? what does it say? something along *undefined function: lista*? you are using the `lista` symbol in first position of a list in a normal evaluation context.
- In order to avoid using an optional argument, define a local function with `labels`. Here is another example to demonstrate how to use labels:

  ```
  (defun tree-occurences (tree number)
    (let ((counter 0))
      (labels ((count-occurences (form)
                 (typecase form
                   (sequence (map nil #'count-occurences form))
                   (number (when (= form number) (incf counter))))))
        (count-occurences tree))
        counter))
  ```

Comment: If it's an atom and not the elem, I thought it would go into the true condition but I dont know what it's supposed to do there. Yes the erro messaje is in the mapcar, it says that List is not a function. I dont know how to use labels

Comment: I mean... I don't know labels so I'm not supposed to use them. I want to solve this somehow using map functions / lambda's

Comment: @Melye77 The thing is: an (atom x) exactly means (not (consp x)), and so a number is an atom. **But**, many other things are atoms too (e.g. strings). And since the `=` function is only defined for numbers (please do read the [spec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eq_sle.htm#EQ), it is not so complex), you will have an error for non-numeric atoms.  I added an example for `labels`.

Comment: Ah ok so I need to use eql instead of =. Cause I do want it to work with chars too

Comment: @Melye77 If you don't have the right to use `labels`, just define an auxiliary function, something like `rec-removal` or `removal-helper`. Yes, you should use `eql`.

Comment: I really want to make it work using map functions. I don't see why I'd need the extra function. I don't understand why mine gives an error in the second condition, when I call removal again.

Comment: Also, I am using an auxiliary variable `counter` and `incf` here above but that's probably not what you are expected to do. Keep it functional and add parameters to your functions in your work. If you need to call mapcar with arguments, wrap the call to a lambda: `(mapcar (lambda (e) (recurse e final)) list)`, though I think you might need to `reduce` here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98206/discussion-between-coredump-and-melye77).

Answer (score 3):

You mention using **mapcar** and **lambda**, but Common Lisp also includes [**mapcan**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) which  might be more useful here.  The **mapcan** function is like mapcar, but instead of creating a list of the function results, it takes the function results and concatenates them into a list.  E.g.,

```
(mapcan (lambda (x)
          (list x x))
        '(1 2 3))
;=> (1 1 2 2 3 3)
```

This is handy for filtering type tasks, because you can have the function that you're mapping over the list always return a list, and if it returns **nil**, then you've essentially filtered out that element.  E.g.:

```
(mapcan (lambda (x)
          (if (evenp x)
              (list x)                  ; if even, return (x)
              '()))                     ; if odd, return ()
        '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
;;=> (2 4 6)
```

So, you can remove an element from all levels of a tree with something like this.  The internal **%remove-all** function does the actual work, but it *always* returns a list, even if the original input wasn't a list.  So, we just have to extract the first element from it afterward.

```
(defun remove-all (element tree &key (test #'eql))
  (labels ((%remove-all (element tree)
             (cond
               ((funcall test element tree) '())
               ((atom tree) (list tree))
               (t (list (mapcan (lambda (child)
                                  (%remove-all element child))
                                tree))))))
    (car (%remove-all element tree))))
```

```
(remove-all 3 '(1 2 3 (3 2 1 (1 3 2))))
;;=> (1 2 (2 1 (1 2)))

(remove-all 3 5)
;;=> 5

(remove-all 3 3)
;;=> NIL

(remove-all 3 '(3))
;;=> NIL
```